# correlation of one variable to all the other in R and p value

Tags: r

I trying to find the correlation of the first variable (age) with all other 10 variables (as opposed to the correlation of all variables with all variables) I also want to extract  the p. values.

I tried this option, but I can't get the p.value from it:

`round(cor(mouse_df[-1], mouse_df$age), 3)`

This doesn't work (I get an incorrect p.value column*):

```
the_test = corr.test(mouse_df[-1], mouse_df$age)
the_table = cbind(the_test$r,the_test$p)

*For example:
corr.test(mouse_df$age, mouse_df$Mm.10)$r
[1] -0.327411
corr.test(mouse_df$age, mouse_df$Mm.10)$p 
[1] 0.04188925

# VS

the_table[1,]
[1] -0.327411  1.000000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try to vectorize the call with `sapply`:

```r
pvals <- sapply(mouse_df[-1], function(x) corr.test(x, mouse_df$age)$p)
rvals <- sapply(mouse_df[-1], function(x) corr.test(x, mouse_df$age)$r)
```

Comment: cool, thanks. I figured out that I had to change an adjustment: the_test = corr.test(mouse_df[-1], mouse_df$age, adjust="none")

Answer (score 0):

For correlations, you can do them all and then select the ones you want:

```
data(mtcars)
r <- cor(mtcars)[1,-1]
r
   cyl   disp     hp   drat     wt   qsec     vs     am   gear   carb 
-0.852 -0.848 -0.776  0.681 -0.868  0.419  0.664  0.600  0.480 -0.551
```

For p.values, we need the `cor.test` function, applied to all columns with the first.

```
p <- sapply(mtcars[,-1], FUN=function(x, y) cor.test(x, y)$p.value, y=mtcars$mpg)
```

Combine r with p:

```
rbind(r, p)
        cyl      disp        hp     drat        wt   qsec       vs       am   gear     carb
r -8.52e-01 -8.48e-01 -7.76e-01 6.81e-01 -8.68e-01 0.4187 6.64e-01 0.599832 0.4803 -0.55093
p  6.11e-10  9.38e-10  1.79e-07 1.78e-05  1.29e-10 0.0171 3.42e-05 0.000285 0.0054  0.00108
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this `dplyr`solution:

```
df %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(cor.test(., 
                                 df$age)$p.value))
  age        v1        v2        v3        v4
1   0 0.9034424 0.1089965 0.3632823 0.5355592
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  age = sample(1:100, 10),
  v1 = rnorm(10),
  v2 = rnorm(10, 1),
  v3 = rnorm(10, 2),
  v4 = rnorm(10, 3)
)
```